# What is the typdef size_t actual code definition

Tags: c, variables, size-t

I am starting to learn c now ,after looking all over I cannot find the actual code definition for **size_t** in the header files.

I am trying to understand how this is defined because I believe it is system dependent.

Can someone direct/show the actual definition code.

Comment: `sizeof` is an operator, not a function.

Comment: Where did you look? The first header to check is `stddef.h`

Comment: checked it cannot see can you copy

Comment: "I am trying to understand how this is defined because I believe it is system dependent." Indeed. "Can someone direct/show the actual definition code."  No, because it is system dependent...

Comment: But it is defined somewhere in the header or am I wrong?

Comment: @YinonDotan You need to be able to find the stddef.h file and look inside it. If you can not find the file or the definition of size_T, your compiler installation is broken.

Comment: If you really took a peek inside the header, you probably noticed it includes other system specific headers. So your search continues...

Comment: size_t is a type definition of unsigned.

Comment: But nowhere in the header I see a line starting with  typedef size_t .

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: It doesn't have to be *directly* in that header. It could be added by a system specific header `stddef.h` includes itself.

Comment: @YinonDotan You shouldn't expect `typedef size_t whatever`, but `typedef whatever size_t`.

Comment: @StoryTeller, that's not correct, the header my be included by another header but if not defined then a compiler error will result.

Comment: I looked at the code in github

Comment: @SPlatten - I suspect you misunderstood my comment.

Comment: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/ginclude/stddef.h. These aren't exactly user-friendly reading, as they are portable to all manner of systems. It says `typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ size_t;` and then in turn you have `#define __SIZE_TYPE__ long unsigned int` before that. For whatever system this was intended.

Comment: @StoryTeller, fair enough.

Comment: I there a code or no that is the question.

Comment: @YinonDotan, its compiler and language dependant, c or c++ and compiler would be helpful.

Comment: Lundin THank you  .

Comment: @StoryTeller: it doesn't have to be physically present in any header file. It could be added automatically by the compiler when it notices the inclusion of a system header.

Comment: @rici - It could. Are you familiar with an implementation that does it like that? Would be an interesting case study

Comment: @StoryTeller: not an extent example, but there are (or were) embedded compilers in which all systems headers are virtual to avoid filesystem dependency. But more common is for the compiler to have a builtin `__size_t` or some such and for `stddef.h` to have `typedef __size_t size_t` which provides no useful information for OP.